# invalid parameter type. Must be one and instanceof LifecycleOwner

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I am trying to use the lifeCycleOwner and lifecycleObserve . I am getting the following exception when i call  **lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().addObserver(this);**

```
invalid parameter type. Must be one and instanceof LifecycleOwner
```

the code as shown below

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);

        new  TestObserver(this,this);
    }   
    }

public class TestObserver implements LifecycleObserver{

  public TestObserver(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner, Context context){
        lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }
}
```

**Edited:**
as requested the Build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

    // ViewModel and LiveData ,lifecycleObserver
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1"

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Comment: Can you share the build.gradle file?

Comment: @Shudipto Trafder added the build.gradle file

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you override onCreate or other events in the LifecycleObserver, don't pass any argument to the method.

This cause your error :

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

This is the right declaration :

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
protected void onCreate()
```

Comment: The marked answer is correct. Whatever method you set @OnLifecycleEvent make sure there are no parameters.

Answer (score 3):

**The marked answer is not correct**.

It is allowed to expect as **first** argument a parameter of type `LifecycleOwner`. Optional it is possible to add as **second** argument, the `Lifecycle.Event`. In the second case, the annotation **must** be `Lifecycle.Event.ON_ANY`. Here are both **working** options:

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
private fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_ANY) // << Must be ON_ANY
private fun onAnyEvent(owner: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) {}
```

---

**Explanation** see source code of `androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache`:
[image]

Comment: You are half correct, the first and the second parameter should be `Class`.

Comment: @LeonWu I don't believe that's correct, `isAssignableFrom` means that the parameter is of that class, not that it is equal to that Class.

Answer (score 0):

This is your Observer Class:

```
public class TestObserver implements LifecycleObserver {

private Activity activity;


public void ActivityRecognitionHelper(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner, Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
    lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
}
```

}

You can call above Observer Class from any activity in following way:

```
new TestObserver().ActivityRecognitionHelper(this, this);
```